# Is it OK to to add negligible risks of errors for performance gains? (fixed hash map bucket size)

Tags: c, optimization, hashmap, data-oriented-design

I have recently been making a custom hash map for a project in C.

My hash map currently works like this:

- the key is hashed via the [Fowler–Noll–Vo 1a hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#FNV-1a_hash) to minimize collisions
- if the number of items exceeds the number of buckets, a rehash is issued in which the number of buckets is doubled
- Every bucket contains an array of items which has to be heap allocated. That means every time a hash map is created, `1 + numberOfBuckets` heap allocations are done.

One problem I currently have with this hash map is that creating it is way too slow for my use case (I have to create a lot of them, in the range of millions).

A simple solution for improving creation speed would have been to only allocate the buckets when needed, but that would essentially just delay the allocations and the performance gain would be minimal.

One idea which also came to mind was to just have a fixed-size array of items per bucket. That way I would only have to make one large heap allocation per map if done right. However, there would be a slight risk of a non-resolvable overflow of the bucket array, especially with a small size. I have [calculated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+%28sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E18+binomial%28n%2C+k%29+%281%2Fn%29%5Ek+%281+-+1%2Fn%29%5E%28n+-+k%29%29%5En%3B+n+%3D+32) that, starting with 32 buckets and a fixed capacity of 18 items, that probability would be around 10^(-19) (if my math is correct), and with more buckets it would grow even smaller. Therefore, the possibility of that error occurring would essentially be negligible.

Especially in the spirit of data-oriented design, I find this concept of a hash map quite interesting, but I couldn't find anything on whether or not ignoring negligible risks of errors is a programming practice that can, is or should even be used at all. I would really like to know if this is a known practice anywhere and if it can be found somewhere else than in hash maps.

Comment: How can we tell how bad it will be for your application if "should not happen" happens?  And what happens after that?  It all depends on the application, Are you controlling a nuclear reactor or are you answering a programming quiz?

Comment: Good point, in my case it is supposed to be a reasonably reliable piece of user space software. I was rather asking a general question regarding programming practice and maybe someone else's prior experience with similar problems, not focusing too much on my particular use case.

Comment: Maybe it's OK, maybe not, risk analysis depends on the context which we don't have. But I can tell you that there are different kinds of hashmap that don't have that risk and are also fast to allocate: the open addressing family of hashmaps

Comment: The model of random distribution of hashes used to calculate the probability of failure is wrong when a malicious actor deliberately skews the data to attack your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the answer is "it depends". Thinking about this problem in the most general way possible there are definitely real consacrated use cases where results are purposefully incorrect for the sake of performance (think distributed systems, [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) as one example). However for any serious system that uses such systems there is an in depth analysis of the tradeoffs (math proofs, market analysis etc.) and a well understanding and acceptance of the tradeoffs.

Going back to your example. For the sake of simplicity lets change the problem a bit. Let's say that in the event of an error the user would get an error message and the application can easily be restarted by the user. That seems fairly reasonable. But is this an acceptable tradeoff **you** are willing to make for the performance benefits? Only you can answer.

Now your real use case is muddied because when the array is overflowed your program has Undefined Behavior. You **can't know** how the program will behave then. You can't even know when and if the program is wrong. Anything can happen. The program can appear to work, can crash, can start giving strange results, really anything. Is that an acceptable tradeoff? Again, only you can answer.

But my two cents is that you should aim first and foremost for a **correct** program. Undefined behavior is really something you don't want in your program (besides buggy behavior it is also a **security** problem). There are definitely ways to speedup allocations, e.g. by using pools, taking care of fragmentation etc. Or there are other kinds of hash maps that are better suited for particular use cases. The subject is well studied. I would suggest you explore those and strongly suggest you don't purposefully add undefined behavior to your program.

Comment: After some further research, I came to realize that there is probably always a more correct but at least equally performant solution that should be used preferably in such cases. I also agree with the comment talking about the security risks such practices might have. Thanks for your elaborate and helpful answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, the authors of the Standard make no attempt to distinguish between situations where it may be acceptable for an application to behave in a manner which is observably (but generally harmlessly) consistent with sequential execution, and those were all possible behaviors should be viewed as equally acceptable.  Thus, achieving optimal balance between performance and the possibility of recoverable faults will often only be possible with implementations that can offer guarantees beyond those mandated by the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to to add negligible risks of errors for performance gains? (fixed hash map bucket size)

Negligible risks (meaning low probability) become apparent when some program loops for one billion times.... unfortunately this has been the source of many errors, after years of production use.  This has had a strong impact on communication protocol design and today strong validation tools are used to test any tiny but possible breach.

This can only be admitted in cases where the human life is not compromised, where there's little impact and when repairing the bug is far more expensive than the consequences or damage the bug can produce.  But sometimes just determining the impact could be costly, so the case in which it could be recommended not repairing the bug are very small.